# Só é gravado a primeira linha de uma tabela dinâmica PHP no Banco MySQL

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Apenas a primeira linha da tabela está gravando no banco de dados, eu pressuponho que o problema está no laço de repetição `foreach ( $_POST['data'] as $key => $value)`.
Ao clicar no botão "Adicionar" será inserido uma nova linha da tabela através de JS, no banco de dados uma assiduidade pode ter várias observações 1:n.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Página:

```
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="table-responsive table-obs">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-highlight">
            <thead>
            <div class="row">
                <th class="col-xs-1">Data</th>
                <th class="col-xs-2">Horário</th>
                <th class="col-xs-3">Horas realizadas</th>
                <th class="col-xs-6">Atividades realizadas/Obsercações</th>
            </div>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="tabelaCorpo">
                <tr id="linhaParaClonar">
                    <td><input type="date" class="form-control" name="data[0]"></td>
                    <td><input type="time" class="form-control" name="horario[0]"></td>
                    <td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="horas-realizadas[0]"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control " name="obs[0]"></td>
                    <td><input type="button" onclick="removerLinha(this)" class="btnX btn btn-danger" value="X"></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-offset-10 col-sm-11">
    <input type="button" onclick="adicionarLinha()" value="Adicionar" class="btn btn-success"/>
</div>

<div class="row" id="box-cinza-inferior">
    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-sm-2">
        <a href="controle-de-fluxo.php" class="btn btn-success">Voltar</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-offset-9">
        <button type="submit" name="btnConcluir" value="0" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
        <button type="submit" name="btnConcluir" value="1" class="btn btn-success">Concluir</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Index.js

```
//Adicionar nova linha na tabela Assiduidade
var max = 10;   //max de 10 campos
var z = 1;
function adicionarLinha() {
    if (z <= max) {
        $('#tabelaCorpo').append('<tr id="linha">\
            <td><input type="date" name="data[' + z + ']" class="form-control" /></td>\
            <td><input type="time" name="horario[' + z + ']" class="form-control" /></td>\
            <td><input type="number" name="horas-realizadas[' + z + ']" class="form-control" /></td>\
            <td><input type="text" name="obs[' + z + ']" class="form-control " /></td>\\n\
            <td><input type="button" onclick="removerLinha(this)" class="btnX btn btn-danger" value="X"></td>\
        </tr>');
        z++;
    }
}
```

Recebe-assiduidade.php

Os outros campos estou conseguindo receber normalmente, mas os dados da tabela está gravando apenas a primeira linha no banco de dados

```
// vincular alunos a tabela observações
foreach ( $_POST['data'] as $key => $value) {
    $data = $_POST['data'][$key];
    $horario = $_POST['horario'][$key];
    $horario = $horario . ":00";
    $horas = $_POST['horas-realizadas'][$key];
    $horas = $horas . ":00:00";
    $obs = $_POST['obs'][$key];

    //echo $data." - ".$horario." - ".$horas." - ".$obs."<br>";

    $sql_code_2 = "INSERT INTO observacoes (id_assiduidade, hr_realizadas, dt, hr_inicio, obs) VALUES ('$id_assiduidade', '$horas', '$data','$horario', '$obs')";
    $sql_query_2 = $mysqli->query($sql_code_2) or die($mysqli->error);
}
```

Comment: 8só ira mandar uma linha mesmo, você tem que criar um loop for para isso

Comment: Não foi isso que aconteceu aqui, veja http://kithomepage.com/sos/gravado.PNG

Comment: Pode testar aqui http://kithomepage.com/sos/primeiraLinha.php

Comment: Leo, uma assiduidade pode ter várias observações, ou seja uma tabela 1:n, no seu exemplo cada observação possui um id diferente na assiduidade.

Comment: Se é para inserir vários valores, melhor usar _prepared statements_ aproveitando que na mysqli eles são reais (e não simulados, como os do PDO foram muito tempo por padrão), ou então gerar várias entradas VALUES de uma vez só. Qualquer uma das duas soluções é melhor do que repetir as _queries_ a cada linha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver, vou deixar documentado caso alguém passe pelo mesmo problema.

A solução foi arrumar a hierarquia da estrutura HTML, estava assim:

`<div>
 <div>
  <div>
   <div>
     <form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
    </form>
</div>`

A solução foi abrir e fechar todas as div dentro do formulário